# Tomcat 10 startup cannot find "java/util/logging/Logger"

Tags: java, tomcat, installation

I've just installed jdk17 on win10 under `D:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.2`

```
C:\Users\xxx>javac -version
javac 17.0.2
```

And I downloaded tomcat10 zip file and unzip it under `E:\wsl\apache-tomcat-10.0.22`

Then I set CATALINA_HOME and PATH:

```
set|findstr CATA
CATALINA_HOME=E:\wsl\apache-tomcat-10.0.22

echo %JRE_HOME%
D:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.2\jre

echo %PATH%
....;E:\wsl\apache-tomcat-10.0.22\bin;E:\wsl\apache-tomcat-10.0.22\lib;

CLASS_PATH=D:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.2\lib\dt.jar;D:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.2\lib\tools.jar;%JRE_HOME%\lib
```

And then in cmd.exe, I ran `startup` or `catalina run` it prints some error message:

```
catalina run
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "E:\wsl\apache-tomcat-10.0.22"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "E:\wsl\apache-tomcat-10.0.22"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "E:\wsl\apache-tomcat-10.0.22\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "D:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.2\jre"
Using CLASSPATH:       "E:\wsl\apache-tomcat-10.0.22\bin\bootstrap.jar;E:\wsl\apache-tomcat-10.0.22\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
Using CATALINA_OPTS:   ""
NOTE: Picked up JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS:  --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
WARNING: Unknown module: java.rmi specified to --add-opens
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/util/logging/Logger
        at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.<init>(DirectJDKLog.java:61)
        at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.getInstance(DirectJDKLog.java:181)
        at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getInstance(LogFactory.java:133)
        at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getInstance(LogFactory.java:156)
        at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:211)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.<clinit>(Bootstrap.java:50)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.util.logging.Logger
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
```

Try to visit localhost:8080, nothing is shown.

What does the above error show? Did I miss anything during setup tomcat?

Thanks.

Comment: `java.util.logging` is the built-in logger.  There's no reason why it might be missing.  Hmm, unless perhaps I see it is part of module `java.logging` and not `java.base`, so perhaps with a newer version of Java it has to be installed separately?  I'm guessing but that might be something to look into. https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.logging/java/util/logging/Logger.html

Answer (score 1):

I finally found that this issue is caused by:

(1) I'm using jdk 17
(2) Software like Tomcat10 and netbeans14 only supports to be run by jdk8-14, not higher version of JRE. This issue exists on windows/linux.

Solution:
Under %JAVA_HOME% remove the jre directory, and replace it with downloaded oracle jre8 directory. Problem solved, both tomcat and netbeans could start.

Mark it.